# WordPress custom login and register working fine on localhost but on site not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello guys this is jack,

i would ask about problem make me confusing
when i made the
custom_login.php for custom login template
custom_register.php for custom register template

it's work fine on localhost but on live version
the custom_login.php not working (displaying without error fine, but not login the user or redirect him to main page)
the **custom_register.php working fine** when user fill up the fields it's **saved on users table** *but* as well will redirect the user after register from **custom-register.php** to **custom-login.php**

the php version on localhost 7.2.9 but on live version is 7.3.15
im not thinking the problem from the verison because the register form work fine? idk you guys can tell me please

i tried to added in **wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

not working as well as **i removed .htaccess** as well not working ;(

the point everything in localhost work much more than perfectly!

**custom_login.php**

```html
<?php
/**
 *
 * Template name: login-page 
 *
 */
# Send the user to his account or any page if already logged in.
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url('/account/') );
}
# Get login error messages.
$login_errors = (isset($_GET['user-login']) ) ? $_GET['user-login'] : 0;     
if ( $_POST['action'] == 'log-in' ) {
    # Submit the user login inputs
    $login = wp_login( $_POST['user-name'], $_POST['password'] );
    $login = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $_POST['user-name'], 'user_password' => $_POST['password'], 'remember' => $_POST['remember-me'] ), false );
    # Redirect to account page after successful login.
    if ( $login->ID ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('account') );      
    }  
} 
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php
wp_head();
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="container text-right" style="position: absolute;
top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);" dir="rtl">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-xl-10">
<div class="card border-0">
<div class="card-body p-0">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="p-5">
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" class="sign-in">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="user-name"><i class="fas fa-user ml-2 mb-2"></i>Username / email address</label>
<input type="text" name="user-name" id="user-name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['user-name'], 1 ); ?>" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-5">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1"><i class="fas fa-lock ml-2 mb-2"></i>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" autocomplete="off" required  />
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Log in'); ?>" class="btn btn-theme">login</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="log-in" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-inline-block">
<div class="account-block rounded-right">
<div class="overlay rounded-right"></div>
<div class="account-testimonial">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/img/logoar.png" style="max-width:200px;bottom:0;position:absolute;"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="text-white text-center mt-3 mb-0">don't have an account yet?<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/register" class="text-white mr-1 font-weight-bold">register new one for free!</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**custom_register.php**

```html
<?php
/**
 *
 * Template name: register-page 
 *
 */
global $wpdb, $user_ID;  

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url('/account/') );
}

if (isset($_POST['user_registeration']))
{
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $phonenumber = esc_html($_POST['phonenumberxc']);
    
    
    if(empty( $username ) || empty( $useremail ) || empty($password))
    {
        $reg_errors->add('field', 'most fill all fields');
    }    
    if ( strlen( $username ) <= 5 )
    {
        $reg_errors->add('username_length', 'username most be at lest 6 letters' );
    }
    if ( username_exists( $username ) )
    {
        $reg_errors->add('user_name', 'this name used in onther account, please chose new one');
    }
    if ( ! validate_username( $username ) )
    {
        $reg_errors->add( 'username_invalid', 'username invalid' );
    }
    if ( !is_email( $useremail ) )
    {
        $reg_errors->add( 'email_invalid', 'email you added invalid' );
    }
    
    if ( email_exists( $useremail ) )
    {
        $reg_errors->add( 'email', 'the email you added existed in another account, please add new one.' );
    }
    if ( strlen( $password ) <= 5 ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'your password must be at lest 6 letters and numbers' );
    }
    
    if (is_wp_error( $reg_errors ))
    { 
        foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error )
        {
             $signUpError = $error ;
        } 
    }
    
    
    if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) )
    {
        // sanitize user form input
        global $username, $useremail;
        $username   =   sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] );
        $useremail  =   sanitize_email( $_POST['useremail'] );
        $password   =   esc_attr( $_POST['password'] );
        
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'    =>   $username,
            'user_email'    =>   $useremail,
            'user_pass'     =>   $password,
            );
        
        $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php
wp_head();
?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-right" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);" dir="rtl">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-xl-10">
<div class="card border-0">
<div class="card-body p-0">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="p-5">
<div class="mb-5">
<h3 class="h4 font-weight-bold text-theme">register new account</h3>
</div>

<form action="<?php echo the_permalink() ?>" method="post" name="user_registeration" class="sign-in">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="user-name"><i class="fas fa-user ml-2 mb-2"></i>username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="user-name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="user-password"><i class="fas fa-lock ml-2 mb-2"></i>password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="user-password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
<label for="email-address"><i class="fas fa-at ml-2 mb-2"></i>email address</label>
<input type="email" name="useremail" class="form-control" id="email-address" autocomplete="off" required  />
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-5">
<label for="phonenumber"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt ml-2 mb-2"></i>phone number</label>
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" autocomplete="off"  />
</div>

<button type="submit" name="user_registeration" class="btn btn-theme">create new account!</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-inline-block">
<div class="account-block rounded-right">
<div class="overlay rounded-right"></div>
<div class="account-testimonial">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/img/logoar.png" style="max-width:200px;bottom:0;position:absolute;"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end card-body -->
</div>
<!-- end card -->
<p class="text-white text-center mt-3 mb-0">already have an account?<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/login" class="text-white mr-1 font-weight-bold">login now!</a></p>
<!-- end row -->
</div>
<!-- end col -->
</div>
<!-- Row -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**funcation.php** for both login , register

```html
//// login - register new page
function redirect_login_page() {

    $login_page  = home_url( '/member-dashboard/' );  
    $register_page  = home_url( '/register/' );  
    $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
    // login
    if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {  
        wp_redirect($login_page);  
        exit;  
    } 
    // regiser
    if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php?action=register" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    wp_redirect($register_page);
    exit;
  }
}  
add_action('init','redirect_login_page');

function login_failed() {
    $login_page  = home_url( '/member-dashboard/' );  
    wp_redirect( $login_page . '?user-login=failed' );  
    exit;  
}  
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed' );  
 
function verify_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {  

    $login_page  = home_url( '/member-dashboard/' );  
    if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {  
        wp_redirect( $login_page . "?user-login=empty" );  
        exit;  
    }  
}  
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_username_password', 1, 3);  


function logout_page() {

    $login_page  = home_url( '/member-dashboard/' );  
    wp_redirect( $login_page . "?user-login=false" );  
    exit;  
}  
add_action('wp_logout','logout_page');
//end login register new page


// no access to wp-admin except admin start
function ace_block_wp_admin() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'ace_block_wp_admin' );
//// no access to wp-admin except admin end

// after register login auto start
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login ); //`[Codex Ref.][1]
    wp_redirect(  home_url( '/account/' ) );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
// after register login auto end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch to find the problem

```
try{
    //your code
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

And print some variables with var_dump()

Comment: code you write it in the right way for me please ..?

Comment: What is the "live action" ? Is it a linux server ?

Comment: @Xaalak i dont know where you saw (live action), but the **localhost** work fine only when i upload it to real website am facing this problems.

Comment: Can you give us the zip file of your app ?

Comment: [link](https://gofile.io/d/4vvIWf) please check it and let me know <3

Comment: what is the function add_filter() in functions.php on line 81 ?

Comment: this for convert from normal date to time ago but i disabled with comment //

Comment: Your code is a mess, I can't believe it works on your pc. For me it doesn't work. There is missing code. I don't see any require_once